# How can I change the background-color to transparent on an onmouseout event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif"              alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
<script>
    function bigImg(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    }
    function normalImg(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "transperant"
    }
</script>
```

I want the background color to go back to transparent after taking the mouse out of the image. Like I put the mouse on it, the background color changes red, I take it out, and the background color goes transparent. The code above works, but only when I hover on it, it changes red, then when I take the mouse out, it still stays the same color.

Comment: use CSS for this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there.

Instead of:

```
x.style.backgroundColor="transperant"
```

It should be:

```
x.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif"              alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">

<script>
    function bigImg(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor = "red"
    }
    function normalImg(x) {
        x.style.opacity = 0.5
    }
</script>
```

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjxpj4xv/)